# PHP Compiler is using 32 bit Architecture on a Raspberry Pi 4 64 bit Kernel

Tags: php, 64-bit, arm64, raspberry-pi4

The **PHP-compiler on my Raspberry Pi 4 is only using 32 bits instead of 64 bits**. I double-checked my kernel-architecture. Everything is configured to 64 bits...

Do i need to add a additional configuration to compile 64 bit php-code?

## PHP test (on my Raspberry Pi 4)

```
$php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'
```

> 2147483647 (**32** bit)

## PHP test (on my PC, 64 bit)

```
php -r 'echo PHP_INT_MAX;'
```

> 9223372036854775807 (**64** bit)

## PHP-Version (on my Raspberry Pi 4)

```
php -v
```

**Result**:

> PHP 8.1.13 (cli) (built: Nov 26 2022 14:29:42) (NTS)
> Copyright (c) The PHP Group
> Zend Engine v4.1.13, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
> with Zend OPcache v8.1.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

## unix name (on my Raspberry Pi 4)

```
uname -a
```

> Linux raspberrypi 5.10.103-v8+ #1529 SMP PREEMPT Tue Mar 8 12:26:46 GMT 2022 **aarch64** GNU/Linux

I already updated to PHP 8.1.13 without any effect.

## EDIT after Comment of Siguza

```
file /bin/bash
```

> bin/bash: ELF **32-bit** LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=3e5e2847bbc51da2ab313bc53d4bdcff0faf2462, stripped

I am not sure, why this comment is printing out "ELF **32-bit** LSB executable".

## Edit after Comment of Nate Eldredge

```
hostnamectl
```

> Static hostname: raspberrypi
> Icon name: computer 
> Machine ID: 082e8c9e42614daa82110aXXXXXXXXXX
> Boot ID: 95b916d95e7d47df92342XXXXXXXXXX
> Operating System: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) 
> Kernel: Linux 5.15.84-v8+ 
> Architecture: arm64

Comment: What do `file /bin/bash` and `file $(which php)` print? It's very possible you have a 64bit kernel but 32bit userland.

Comment: `file /bin/bash`

ELF **32-bit** LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=3e5e2847bbc51da2ab313bc53d4bdcff0faf2462, stripped

`file $(which php)`

/usr/bin/php: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/php

Seems like something is wrong. I don't know why 32bit is printed there...

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using, and how did you install it?  Also, how did you install your kernel?

Comment: I added the Information to the article. I followed this article to update to 64Bits:  https://www.bastianoso.de/tipps-tricks/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-os-auf-64-bit-umstellen.html

Comment: @xy8000: From that article (translated): "With the switch from the Raspberry Pi OS to 64-bit, we have both the CPU and the operating system on 64-bit, while most programs are still running in 32-bit".  So indeed, only your kernel is 64 bits, not userland programs like php.  You *might* be able to install a 64-bit php as [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO), but AFAIK this is not officially supported for Raspbian, and is painful even if it does work.  You'll be much happier in the long run if you start over and install a fully 64-bit distro.  Ubuntu for instance works fine.

Comment: @NateEldredge: Thanks for your reply. That could be the problem. I will add the solution  to the question.

Comment: @xy8000 Do not add the solution to your question. Instead, post an answer below the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution (see comment from Nate Eldredge):

I followed this [german article](https://www.bastianoso.de/tipps-tricks/raspberry-pi/raspberry-pi-os-auf-64-bit-umstellen.html) to upgrade the kernel to 64bits. **Nate Eldredge** responded with a possible solution.
Quoted Comment:

> From that article (translated): "With the switch from the Raspberry Pi OS to 64-bit, we have both the CPU and the operating system on 64-bit, while most programs are still running in 32-bit". So indeed, only your kernel is 64 bits, not userland programs like php. You might be able to install a 64-bit php as multiarch, but AFAIK this is not officially supported for Raspbian, and is painful even if it does work. You'll be much happier in the long run if you start over and install a fully 64-bit distro. Ubuntu for instance works fine.